# Hide menu item in main menu?

Tags: compact-framework

How can I hide and show a menu item in the main menu of a form? The `System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem`class doesn't have the `Visible` property.

Comment: Can you just remove/add it as necessary?

Comment: Add and remove is the way I do it on mine, too.